# Cold Fusion create web service with "new" operator

Tags: web-services, coldfusion

Can a web service be created in CFScript using the **New** operator?

As opposed to CreateObject..

```
Application.UserWebService = CreateObject("webservice", "http://WebServiceURL/WebServices/UserService.asmx?WSDL");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the CF docs, the only one I saw was using the CreateObject..

```
<cfscript> 
ws = CreateObject("webservice",  
"http://www.xmethods.net/sd/2001/TemperatureService.wsdl"); 
xlatstring = ws.getTemp(zipcode = "55987"); 
writeoutput("The temperature at 55987 is " & xlatstring); 
</cfscript>
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-78b4.html

Answer (score 4):

No. The `new` operator only works with components, and a web service is not a component.

FWIW, you can take a look inside the `{cfroot}\CustomTags\com\adobe\coldfusion`  directory to get an idea of which core objects *are* implemented as components.